# Convert List of Objects to List of Strings

Tags: string, list, listview, javafx, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring data jpa `findAll()` method. So it returns List of objects.
here is the entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@Data
public class CountryEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "country_name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="countryEntity")
    private Collection<GovernmentEntity> governments;
}
```

and data jpa `findAll()` method is

```
 List<CountryEntity> entities = countryRepo.findAll();
```

I want to get list of Country names as String **WITHOUT USING loops or streams** (performance issues).

I used streams and it works fine with javaFx ListView

```
@FxmlView("/address.fxml")
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HomeController implements Initializable {

private ObservableList<String> countriesNames;
 @FXML
 private ListView<String> countryListView;

 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        List<CountryEntity> entities = countryRepo.findAll();
        List <String> countryList = entities.stream().map(o-> Objects.toString(o.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        countriesNames = FXCollections.observableList(countryList);
        countryListView.getItems().addAll(countriesNames);
}
}
```

Comment: work through a tutorial about how to use listView, in particular on how to configure the visual representation of its items

Comment: of course i will
thanks kleopatra

Answer (score 2):

Make your `ListView` a `ListView<CountryEntity>`, and use a cell factory to customize the display:

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    private ObservableList<String> countriesNames;
    @FXML
    private ListView<CountryEntity> countryListView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        List<CountryEntity> entities = countryRepo.findAll();
        countryListView.getItems().addAll(entities);
        countryListView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<CountryEntity>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(CountryEntity country, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(country, empty);
                if (empty || country == null) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    setText(country.getName()); // or however you want to display it
                }
        }); 
    }
}
```

---

If you genuinely only want a list of country names, and don't want to retrieve a list of `CountryEntity`s and extract the names from them, then you need to define a method in your repository for the purpose:

```
public interface CountryEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<CountryEntity, Long> {

    // existing methods...

    @Query("select c.name from CountryEntity c")
    List<String> findCountryNames() ;

}
```

And then of course just do

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> countryListView ;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    countryListView.getItems().addAll(countryRepo.findCountryNames());
}
```

However, the first approach is almost certainly preferred. You will likely need the other data in the `CountryEntity` at some point.

Comment: thanks a lot
you're a hero